# nothing works well in mat-sidenav-container angular material 5

Tags: html, angular-material, routerlink, sidenav, angular-routerlink

I'm using angular 5 and angular material. i have a `mat-sidenav-container` that consists of `mat-sidenav` and a `mat-sidenav-content`. and I have a mat-toolbar in the top of my page. I want to use routerLink in my `sidenav-content` but it's not working however it works in my mat-toolbar. even a button click function is not working. here are my codes below

```
<mat-toolbar>
    <mat-toolbar-row>
        <div>
            <button mat-icon-button class="button" (click)="sidemenu.toggle()">
        <mat-icon class="menu">menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
        </div>
        <div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image"></div>
    </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
<mat-sidenav-container class="example-container">
    <mat-sidenav mode="side" opened #sidemenu>
        <mat-nav-list>
            <mat-list-item appAccordionLink>
                <a appAccordionToggle>
                    <mat-icon class="list-icon">inbox</mat-icon>
                    <span class="link">IncomingMail</span>
                    <span fxFlex></span>
                </a>
            </mat-list-item>
        </mat-nav-list>
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content>
        <a routerLink="/">Home</a>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Comment: Do you get any error? "...not working" isn't enough. Try to debug the app and drop more infos/details please.

Comment: I don't get any errors. everything in the sidenav-container such as button or inputs doesn't work

Comment: Even this is not working? <mat-sidenav-content><button mat-raised-button [routerLink]="['/']" >Home</button></mat-sidenav-content>

Comment: @k.vincent no it's not working. I can see the button but when I click on it, nothing happens. it happens for input and other elements in HTML. they're not working. should I import a module beside MatSidenavModule? is MatSidenavModule enough?

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "it happens for input and other elements in HTML"?

Comment: @farbia: Can you please add the code to your router code you're using. I mean where you define the routes.

Comment: @k.vincentI mean that even if I use an input, it's not working and I cant type in the input form. is it related to my routes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169155/discussion-between-k-vincent-and-fariba-j).

Comment: Let's continue in chat